# Looping through radio buttons, hiding unslected ones

Tags: jquery, radio-button, show-hide, selected

I have groups of radio buttons, what I am trying to do is to loop through and hide the radio and label of any unselected ones (addClass .hiddenRadio). The other side of this is I need to enable them again on another event click

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="sex_1" value="male" /><label>Male</label>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="sex_1" value="female" /><label>Female</label>

<input class="radio" type="radio" name="sex_2" value="male" /><label>Male</label>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="sex_2" value="female" /><label>Female</label>
```

Male
   Female

Comment: You really should add `id` attributes to your `input` elements, and corresponding `for` attributes to your `label` elements. Otherwise, the labels won't work as expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the following which selects all unchecked inputs with the `radio` class and hides the corresponding label:

```
$(".radio:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    // If you the hiddenRadio class added to both
    $(this).addClass("hiddenRadio").next().addClass("hiddenRadio");

    // Otherwise if you just want to hide the label
    $(this).addClass("hiddenRadio").next().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Two lines of code is really enough:

```
$("input[type=radio]:not(:checked)").addClass("hiddenRadio");
$("input[type=radio]:not(:checked) + label").addClass("hiddenLabel");
```

No need for loops using `each()` or manually finding labels using `next()` - just let the selectors do their job!

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate *(not hiding, but changing color)*:

http://jsfiddle.net/bZcHq/

Also, there is no need for adding `class='radio'` to every radio button. The attribute selector `[type=radio]` will suffice, as long as you don't plan on supporting IE6.

Comment: you need to add the sibling labels as well

Comment: Each element of type `radio` is `input` therefore `$("[type=radio]:not(:checked)")` also works

Comment: @abuduba including the tag with the class is faster in jQuery (Sizzle) http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/

Comment: I know, but the difference in tiny :)

Comment: @abuduba That is true in this case, but not necessarily for the rest of the solution. The `type` attribute is also valid on `a`, `link`, `object`, and other elements. However, the `radio` value should only occur on `input` elements, but still...

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/GTzL4/4/

**HTML**

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="sex_1" value="male" checked /><label>Male</label>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="sex_1" value="female" /><label>Female</label>

    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="sex_2" value="male" /><label>Male</label>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="sex_2" value="female" checked /><label>Female</label>

<button onclick="hideUnSelected()">Hide</button>
<button onclick="showAll()">Show</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

**JS**

```
function hideUnSelected(){
    $('.radio:not(:checked)').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hidden').next('label').addClass('hidden');
    });
}
function showAll(){
    $('.radio').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hidden').next('label').removeClass('hidden');
    });
}
```